# Building a large multiselect in React without it being really slow

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, multi-select

The app I'm building needs a rather substantial multiselect. It works in the user interface, as I'm using [this library](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) which lets people search through the options, but I can't get it to render in a reasonable time in React.

[Link to JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ach1d7x9/)

I've made a much simpler version that shows the same issue.

It contains some setup code, which creates a list of 500 items. It also makes a list of which items should be selected by default. Right now I have it set to `x%1` so every option is on by default, because this appears to be the bottleneck. I also initiate the `startTime` variable just to track things.

```
var list = [];
var defaultList = [];
for (var x = 0; x < 500; x += 1) {
  list.push(x);
  if (x%1 === 0) {
    defaultList.push(x)
  }
}
var startTime=new Date().getTime();
```

Then we pass that into a component with `ReactDom.render()`, which has a callback to alert how many milliseconds have passed once it's rendered:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello
    list={list}
    defaultList={defaultList}  
  />,
  document.getElementById('container'),
  ()=>{
    alert(new Date().getTime() - startTime)
  }
);
```

And finally, the component itself, which just makes a simple multiselect with all the options in `list` and checks by default all the options in `defaultList`:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <select defaultValue={this.props.defaultList} multiple>
        {this.props.list.map(item => {
            return (<option value={item} key={item}>{item}</option>)
        })}
      </select>
    )
  }
});
```

Running this fiddle on my computer yields an alert that shows **over 1000 milliseconds** to render this component. If I change the qualifier for default list from `x%1` to `x%50`, so there are 10 selected items, it only takes 76 milliseconds.

At first, I assumed that the bottleneck was just building the 500 `option` elements, but it seems like the slowdown actually comes from using a large number of defaults.

So I guess my questions are:

- Does anyone know a way to get the same results to render much faster?
- Am I missing some insight when it comes to React performance?
- Why would adding defaults add so much overhead?

Thanks.

And please note, I *am* aware that React is going to run slower in JSFiddle, and that in production I should use the production version of React, *and* that if I didn't make my list 500 items long it wouldn't take so long. These aren't the answers I'm looking for.

EDIT: It looks like React might be marking each `option` as `selected` one at a time, resulting in 500 rerenders. That might explain what's happening - is this a bug in React? I'm seeing a 'Forced synchronous layout is a possible performance bottleneck.' warning in Chrome Developer Tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is the first render of the DOM being slow. Take this code:

```
let html = '<select multiple>'
for (var x = 0; x < 500; x += 1) {
  html += `<option value=${x} selected>${x}</option>`
}
html += '</select>'

var startTime=new Date().getTime();

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html;

alert(new Date().getTime() - startTime)
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/769y95nc/1/)

It performs the same as yours react-code on my machine (Chrome 47, Windows 10), about 5000ms.

If I use Microsoft Edge, the time goes from 5000ms to 231ms (react) and 12ms (DOM-manipulation). Here Chrome DOM is slow (compared to Edge) and the option-elements must be rendered to DOM eventually. Updating might be faster.

I've made some code which does the same, but is not a `<select>` field. It's a unordered list, with list items having click handlers. Performance is about 10x better (Chrome ~500ms, Edge ~300ms).

```
class Select extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
    this.state.selected = props.selected
  }
  handleClick () {
    this.setState({selected: !this.state.selected})
  }
  render () {
    const val = this.props.value
    const selected = this.state.selected
    return (
      <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} className={selected ? 'selected' : ''}>
        {val}
      </li>
    )
  }
}

const Hello = ({list, defaultList}) => 
  <ul>
    {list.map(item =>
      <Select key={item} value={item} selected={defaultList.indexOf(item) !== -1}/>)}
  </ul>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6m6072x/)

Comment: Yes, if you profile with the timeline, you can see that this creates a ton of recalculated styles. This happens even without React.

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer correct, as it is just something to do with Chrome's rendering, not React. I've filled the bug with Chrome though, as the same thing runs in Firefox, Safari, and IE in about a tenth of the time or less.